# custom config section seems to load the wrong file

Tags: .net, configurationsection

Hi I'm creating a library (DLL) for which I want to load the .config file (DLL_name.config) and in which I have implemented a custom section. I'm using OpenEXEConfiguration and it loads the file, Configuration object has the right FilePath value (pointing straight to my "DLL_name.config" file), but it contains 21 .net sections (system.net, system.web, etc) but not my custom section. Note that the only section appearing in my config file is my custom one, so I don't understand why the file path seem ok but the content is not the one from the file specified in that path O_o

Here is my config file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="AcceptedStereotypesSection" type="EAReferentialAddInConfigs.CustomConfigs.IntegrityCheck.AcceptedStereotypesSection, EAReferentialAddInConfigs"/>
  </configSections>
  <AcceptedStereotypesSection>
    <AcceptedStereotypes>
      <AcceptedStereotype Stereotype="Test1">
      </AcceptedStereotype>
    </AcceptedStereotypes>
  </AcceptedStereotypesSection>
</configuration>
```

Here's my custom section classes:

```
public class AcceptedStereotypesSection: ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("AcceptedStereotypes", IsDefaultCollection = true, IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
    public AcceptedStereotypeCollection AcceptedStereotypes
    {
        get
        {
            return base["AcceptedStereotypes"] as AcceptedStereotypeCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            base["AcceptedStereotypes"] = value;
        }
    }
}

public class AcceptedStereotypeCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new AcceptedStereotype();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((AcceptedStereotype)element).Stereotype;
    }

    protected override string ElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return "AcceptedStereotype";
        }
    }

    protected override bool IsElementName(string elementName)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(elementName) && elementName == ElementName;
    }

    public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap;
        }
    }

    public AcceptedStereotype this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseGet(index) as AcceptedStereotype;
        }
    }

    public new AcceptedStereotype this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseGet(key) as AcceptedStereotype;
        }
    }
}

public class AcceptedStereotype:ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Stereotype", IsKey = true)]
    public String Stereotype
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)this["Stereotype"];
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("AcceptedRelationships", IsDefaultCollection = true, IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
    public AcceptedRelationshipCollection AcceptedRelationships
    {
        get
        {
            return base["AcceptedRelationships"] as AcceptedRelationshipCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            base["AcceptedRelationships"] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried both

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

and

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config" };
        Configuration config2 = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

but always getting same result: filepath is ok but content does not represent my above custom section...

Note that this DLL is used as a plugin extending a product named Sparx Enterprise Architect, so is has to be registered for COM interop... Dunno why that would make a difference but still wanted to mention it just in case :)

Any idea as to why this strange behavior occurs would be very appreciated. I could always open up the config file manually and browse the XML, but this is not a very elegant solution and would rather avoid it...

Thanks